# Very simple jQuery UI tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I replicated the example of this site:
http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#default

Html:

```
<h3 title='this is the title of hello world'>hello world</h3>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).tooltip();
});
```

But it's still shows the regular tooltip only.

JSFiddle with added CSS resource:
http://jsfiddle.net/HjPtJ/

Comment: Wrong jQuery version => off-topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can read here http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/ the tooltip widget is added in jQuery UI version 1.9, the JSFiddle has jQuery UI 1.8 added.